# Add a contextual filter to a view based on taxonomy term programatically?

Tags: 7, views

I have content type called "Article", in this content there is a field called "topic" which is a auto complete field and it is taxonomy term.

There is a taxonomy called "topic" and terms in this taxonomy are "Red 2015","Red 2016","Red 2017","Red 2018".

I created 3 nodes under this "article" content type and selected topic field as "Red 2017"

And the node url is coming like this "www.qwerty.com/top-10-red-2017-18".

I want to create Contextual filters by giving a condition like that if the url contain year  2017 then consider the taxonomy term "Red 2017" content and fetch recent 3 node coming under article content type and node coming under taxonomy term "Red 2017"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it by regexing the url is messy and prone to error. You just need to load the node, get the term id and send it to the view.

In your view's contextual filter, instead of "Provide default", select "Hide view". Views has no way of getting the term from the currently viewed node by itself so we'll provide it with a module called `custom_taxonomy`.

**custom_taxonomy.module**

```
<?php

function custom_taxonomy_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args){ 
    // Check for view
    if($view->name == 'block_under_article') {
        // Current URL
        $url = explode('/', current_path());
        // Check we have a node ID. This ignores aliases.
        if (isset($url[1]) && is_numeric($url[1])) {
            // Load node to get taxonomy
            $current_node = node_load($url[1]);
            // Check taxonomy is set
            if (isset($current_node->field_topic['und'][0]['tid'])) {
                // Send it to the view
                $args[0] = $current_node->field_topic['und'][0]['tid'];
            }           
        }       
    }
}
```

Just change the view name and check that the field name is correct. This assumes that there is that the field_focus contextual filter is at the top of the list. If it isn't, you can use `$args[1] $args[2]` etc.

If your `www.qwerty.com/top-10-red-2017-18` page isn't an article or something you can add that taxonomy field to, then you'd need to do something like below..

```
if (strpos(current_path(), '2017') !== false) {
    $args[0] = 123; // The tid of the 2017 term
}
```

Comment: How can I create contextual filter for this condition? Which field i want to add in contextual filter? Is it url or taxonomy term field?

Comment: It should be the `Taxonomy term: Term ID` filter. Test the view first using the preview and typing in the tid.